# Integral of a complex quantity (too long to display in title)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am trying to compute the following quantity :

$\int\frac{(\epsilon^{2}-4)}{\bigg|2^{-L-1}\left((\epsilon-\Delta^{2}\epsilon+4i\Delta)((\lambda^{+})^{L}-(\lambda^{-})^{L})+(\Delta^{2}+1)\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}-4}((\lambda^{+})^{L}+(\lambda^{-})^{L})\right)\bigg|^{2}}d\epsilon$

where $\lambda^{+}=\epsilon+\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}-4}$, $\lambda^{-}=\epsilon-\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}-4}$, $\Delta \in \mathbb R$ and $L \in \mathbb N, L\geq 2$.

Remarkably, numerics show that this integral is *independent* of $L$.

For $\Delta=1$, the answer is $\pi/4$.

For big values of $L$, the plot of the integrand show an interesting oscillating pattern around an enveloppe. (here for $L=50$ and $\Delta=1$)

[image]

Any insight is most welcome.

Comment: I don't even want to look at it

Comment: How in the world did you come across something like this? I would be exceptionally shocked if you could do anything except approximate something this demonic.

Comment: Long story short, it comes from physics. This is the expression of the conductivity for a free fermionic chain coupled to external baths. At least there should be some argument to say that the integral is $L$ independent.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you can actually push the analytics pretty far for the large $L$ case in which the support of the function is $[-2,2]$ (up to corrections of order $1/C^L$ where $C>2$).

Within this approximation the trigonometric substitution $\epsilon =2\sin\theta $ works well and simplifies the integrand greatly.One gets :

$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{3}(\theta)}{2\left(\sin^{2}((\theta+\pi/2)L))+\cos^{2}\theta(\cos^{2}((\theta+\pi/2)L))\right)}d\theta$

One can show for instance that it is lower bounded by $ \cos^3\theta/2$ and upper bounded by $\cos\theta /2$.

Now remains the intriguing fact that the integral is independent of $L$ for *any* $L$. For large $L$ from this expression it shouldn't be suprising since the speed of the oscillations shouldn't matter as long as it is "fast enough". But from numerics this should be an exact result...